# Enabled symlinks, but fire-app-builder wont work still

Tags: android, git, symlink, amazon-fire-tv

I'd like to think I am fairly experienced with Android Studio after a year of playing around with it in my spare time. I've recently wanted to start developing for the Amazon Fire Stick/TV, so I followed the tutorial [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/fire-app-builder-download-and-build), word for word.

The problem I'm encountering has to do with the symbolic linking. I've typed the enable command into both the git and Windows command windows. When I check the status of symlinks in my git shell, it returns `true`. But when I compile the program my `values-en-rUS/strings.xml` reads

> "../values/strings.xml"

Any help will be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L.Mellor, I updated the Fire App Builder docs with some more instructions that should hopefully address this issue. See the following:

- [Download and Build Fire App Builder](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/fire-app-builder-download-and-build)
- [Configure Symlinks for Windows Without Admin Privileges](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/fire-app-builder-configure-windows-symlinks-no-admin-priv)

In particular, after cloning the repo, run the scripts in that second link.

If you have the chance to try this out and it solves the issue, will you let me know? Thanks.